# multiple pdf download using zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, pdf

i got this code in attaching a pdf file to my site in order for the viewers to download such pdf file..

$fullPath = "../public/pdffiles/FolioPlusUserGuide(v3.0).pdf";

```
    if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {

        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");            
        header("Content-length: $fsize");
        header("Cache-control: private");

        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
            echo $buffer;
        }
    }

    fclose ($fd);
    exit;
```

html code:

baseUrl().'/DownloadPdf'?>">DOWNLOAD BROCHURE

this code only accommodates 1 file path, I have more pdf files with different filename and different buttons for each to handle the download event. how can i achieve this?..thanks ahead!..=)

Comment: $filepath variable could be anything you want, change it per PDF file. If you want user to download multiple PDF files in a single HTTP request, you have to zip them with PHP zip library in a single file. So what exactly you are looking to do?

Comment: what i want is for the buttons to hold different pdf filenames since no two buttons should have the same pdf file..the code i used only catered 1 filepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass PDF file name via HTTP request, like this:

DownloadPDF.php?filename=test1.pdf

Then in your DownloadPDF file have something like this:

```
$pdfdir = "/pdffiles/folder/location/here";
$pdffilename = $_GET['filename'];
$fullPath = $pdfdir.$pdffilename;

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {

        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");            
        header("Content-length: $fsize");
        header("Cache-control: private");

        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
            echo $buffer;
        }
    }

    fclose ($fd);
    exit;
```

Now your code is dynamic and you can download any PDF with links like this:

```
<a href=downloadpdf.php?filename=something.pdf>Something</a>
<a href=downloadpdf.php?filename=something2.pdf>Something2</a>
```

etc.

Comment: @cfz This obviously only is sample code. A real-world application shall limit the allowed filename values so that only explicitly released files can be downloaded.

Comment: i tried it but it's not working..it only redirects me to an empty page when i clicked the button

Comment: you have to double check everything, overall code looks fine.

Comment: i think the problem is within this line $pdfdir = "/pdffiles/folder/location/here";..what i did is add the filepath of the folder containing my pdf files but it does not work..

Comment: You have to change that accordingly for your own server and site setup, you can't copy paste it. You have to modify it for your server, that is just a sample psuedo code.

Comment: filepath is internal or relative path and should end with a slash. What you entered in that?